# Open a div on the page in a new window while maintaining the ability to update it via websockets

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to have a section of the page (where i have notifications) open in a new window (new browser window) while maintaining the ability to get websocket updates so the notifications can be received on both windows when something gets updated.

I am wondering if there is anyway to do this using jQuery or any other method. The framework I  am using is backbone if that matters.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: If the window is opened by JS, it's accessible via JS so DOM manipulations can be done. Sockets have nothing to do with this.

Comment: What do you mean? If I open a completely new window via JS, how will it continue to get websocket updates? A little more of an explanation would be great. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The window does NOT get "weboscket updates". A websocket client receives data. Forget websockets for now. Only think about the _data_ you already have at hand. Now, what I'm saying is that you CAN update an element in another window with that data.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying. basically get it in one place and update it in another, makes sense. Is there a way you can help by providing an example of how to open something in a new window and continue to update it from the other? Again, appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

html

```
<textarea placeholder="click `open popup`
to open and update"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="open">
<input type="button" value="close">
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $("input[value=open]").focus().one("click", function () {
        $("body").append("<br /><span class=update></span>");
        var popup = window.open("", "popup", "width=200, height=100");
        popup.document.write("popup ready");
        $(".update").html("popup ready");
        popup.focus();

        $("textarea").on("change", function (e) {
            popup.document.write($(this).val() + "<br />");
            $(".update").html(function (i, o) {
                return o + $(e.target).val() + "<br />";
            });
            $(this).val("");
            return popup.focus();
        }).change();

        $("input[value=close]").on("click", function () {
            popup.close();
            return $("textarea").attr("placeholder", "popup closed");
        });
        return $("textarea").attr("placeholder", "popup ready to update");
    });    
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/b2e7t/